# Determine if any objects from a particular assembly are being stored in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm working on an ASP.NET site that uses both Entity Framework and RedisSessionStateProvider. In some of the older code on the site, the Entity Framework code was still using Dynamic Proxies. The newer code does not.

Intermittently, we are getting an error:

```
Unable to find assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyDataDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

when RedisSessionStateProvider tries to deserialize a session. I've gone through and looked at everywhere I can think of that Session is set and that might be storing proxies in the session. But I have clearly missed something somewhere.

So I wanted to attack it from the other side and examine what is in Session and find the offending objects, which will likely lead me to the location in code at which they were set.

So to do that, I need to examine everything that is stored in Session and determine if it is an object of a type from that Dynamic Proxies assembly.

To further complicated this need:

1. The objects are likely not directly stored in session. They're more likely in properties or even private fields on the objects that are stored in session. It could be many layers deep in that kind of hierarchy.
2. The objects I am looking for will *never* be the explicit return type of a field/property. They will always be derived from the explicit return type. So we can't look at just the return types of properties/fields on a particular type - we need to actually get the value of it and check the true type of the value.

I've written some code that does this already that is something like

```
foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
{
    var obj = Session[key];
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Spelunk(obj);
    }
}

private void Spelunk(object o)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();

    if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string) || t == typeof(DateTime))
        return;

    if (t.AssemblyQualifiedName.IndexOf("AssemblyNameIAmLookingFor", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Found {t.AssemblyQualifiedName}!!!");
    }

    var pubs = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    var nonPubs = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (var pub in pubs)
    {
        var val = pub.GetValue(o);
        if (val != null)
        {
            Spelunk(val);
        }
    }

    // Repeat for nonPubs
}
```

However, I'm fairly certain I am missing something here. Generics come to mind.  But I'm almost not sure what else I might be missing. And like SLaks mentioned below, the recursive nature of this code will be problematic.

Is there any better way to do this? Any easy way to dive through an object graph and test for things in a specific assembly? An easier way to achieve my main goal?

Comment: Beware that you will recurse forever if the fields have a cycle (which is quite likely)

Comment: Also, your reasons are relevant; this is a strange thing to do.  For example, you may want a Roslyn analyzer, or a memory dump.

Comment: @SLaks Yeah, I've run into that already. I added a check if I had already checked that particular type before, but that violates #2 because a particular member might have been null or a non-derived type the first time through, but the second time through it could be the right thing. So I need to switch it to be non-recursive, though that has its own pitfalls too. And on your other comment, I'll update it with my reasons

Comment: Alright, updated with more details